# C++ run a function in async and not block the ui

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I have a small app that checks the dotnet framework, if it is not installed it will install it

Now when the application starts i want to popup a gif image with something like loading and in background check the framework and install.

the catch here is that it can not have any prerequisite to run the application

here is what i have till now

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                  _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                  _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine,
                  _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
       int exitCode = -1;
       showPic(hInstance);
       MessageBox(0L, L"Dotnet will installed", L"Alert", 0);
       auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, DoWork, hInstance, lpCmdLine);
       fut.wait();
       exitCode = fut.get();
       return exitCode;
}
```

showPic()

```
void showPic(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    loadImage(hInstance);
    // create window
    wnd = createWindow(hInstance);
    SetWindowLong(wnd, GWL_STYLE, 0);
    ShowWindow(wnd, SW_SHOW);
}
```

loadImage(HINSTANCE hInstance)

```
void loadImage(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    imageDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    imageBmp = LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));
    imageBmpOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(imageDC, imageBmp);
}
```

Now what is happening here is that the if i dont show the messagebox the picture does not load in the window, and still the window goes into not responding mode also i could not get it work with gif, only with bmp images
any help is appriciated

now since i wait for fut it is obvious that it will block the ui until it has the value, what is the workaround for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be simple. Create the window, show it, call the thread, go to main message loop. When thread is done it will destroy the window.

```
struct T_data {
    HWND hWnd;
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    LPTSTR cmdline;
    int exitCode;
};

DWORD WINAPI taking_too_long(LPVOID p) {
    Sleep(2000); //wait at least 2 seconds!
    T_data* data = reinterpret_cast<T_data*>(p);
    auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, DoWork, data->hInstance, data->lpCmdLine);
    fut.wait();
    data->exitCode = fut.get();
    //make sure the window handles IDM_EXIT to close itself
    PostMessage(data->hWnd, WM_COMMAND, IDM_EXIT, 0);
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int) {
    T_data data;
    data.exitCode = -1;
    data.hWnd = hWnd;
    data.hInstance = hInstance;
    data.cmdline = lpCmdLine;

    data.hWnd = showPic(hInstance);

    CreateThread(NULL, 0, taking_too_long, &data, 0, NULL);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return data.exitCode;
}
```

Comment: @Barmak: What a nice example of the proper usage of CreateThread in combination with std::future, std::async and PostMessage. I really appreciate this one and would like to ask: Is this so GENERAL that it can be told a "everyday-life-example" ?

Comment: I find it hard to see why async would be used here.

Comment: @David: You are right, because we especially should not need this "double" approach, either CreatreThread or std::async. Or not ?

Comment: @icbytes Two obvious approaches. Use `CreateThread` and wait in the thread for the task to complete. Or use an `async` but run a message loop using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: @icbytes Not in comments to another question!

Comment: *Is this so GENERAL that it can be told a "everyday-life-example"* @icbytes I wouldn't say general but it should be okay in some other places. One problem is that stack data can go out of scope when using `PostMessage` (`SendMessage` would be similar in this case). In above example it's okay because stack data is in `WinMain`. Or just use global variables to exchange data between threads.